# will ANN identify a feature that has no influence?

Tags: neural-network, features

I am doing my first steps in training ANN, one of the features in my data `X` is `user_id`.

Assuming `user_id` has no influence over `y`, is it o.k to leave it in `X`? Is it safe to assume that the NN will learn to ignore that feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you **know** (emphasis on knowing, not assuming, or guessing) that a feature has no influence, you gain nothing by keeping it in.

"Best" case scenario, it ignores it, as it should, and you now have a larger model that you'd need. Remember the Occam's razor principle ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor))

"Worst" case scenario, it somehow learns that the id has a huge impact on your output, and your results are really strange.

> Is it safe to assume that the NN will learn to ignore that feature?

If you have "enough" data, this will probably happen. But it also depends on how informative your other features are, how easy your problem is etc. As mentioned above, why risk it when you can simply ignore it.

Comment: it's not a practical question, more of a wondering.  While I dropped the feature I wondered if I can just leave it, since after the train I want to predict on all the data-set and want to have the user ID so if the NN can ignore the field it will save me df.drop, then to add the id.

Comment: Fair enough. But I think the extra lines of code are worth the certainty you won't get weird results